# Using baposter: position logos

Tags: baposter

I am preparing a poster, and the problem I have is that the logo stays center to the line of title, while i wanna it to respect the top margin. any idea how to do that?

```
{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{LOGO1}}  %%%Added left logo
{\sf\bf \smaller What I talk about} % Poster title
{\vspace{0.2em} I am the speaker} % Author names
{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{LOGO2}}
```

beside, how can I add a box the title part?

Comment: Hi naw, please post a complete `.tex` file, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Then I or others can reproduce your problem and start thinking about a solution.

Comment: it's in baposter, the logos are always aligne to the center of the title line, while I wanna it to the top.
http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/conference-posters

Comment: My comment above still applies. Please edit your answer to include the contents of a complete tex file. I want to be able to paste it into my editor, hit 'compile', and see your situation in front of me. Then I can start thinking about a solution. 'Help me to help you' and all that...

Comment: Txs John, I got an answer that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
{\parbox[top][6em][t]{10em}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{LOGO1}}}
{\sf\bf\smaller\fbox{What I talk about}}
{\vspace{0.2em} I am the speaker}
{\parbox[top][6em][t]{10em}{\hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{LOGO2}}}
```

Also make sure that `eyecatcher=yes`.